# rails_admin: id field clickable and redirect to the show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

I am using `rails_admin` gem for my rails project

I need to make the id column clickable, so when I click on the object's id I can be redirected to the show action

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone answered my issue on Github , [here is the link](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/2717)

it can be done like that

```
config.model Booking do
    list do
      field :id do
        formatted_value do
          path = bindings[:view].show_path(model_name: 'Booking', id: bindings[:object].id)
          bindings[:view].link_to(bindings[:object].id, path)
        end
      end
  ....
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  rails_admin do
    list do
      field :id do
        pretty_value do
          %(<a href="/admin/#{bindings[:object].class.name.downcase}/#{bindings[:object].id}">#{bindings[:object].id}</a>).html_safe
        end
      end
    end
  end
```